# Why aren't the strong LLNs and CLT contradicting each other?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Given $n$ [i.i.d.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) random variables $\{X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n\}$, each with mean $M$ and variance $V$, both [strong and week LLNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) seem to say that the average of the $n$ random variables, $S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n }{n}$, approaches $M$, as $n \to \infty$. The [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) seems to say that, as $n \to \infty$, the distribution of this average $S_n$ approaches a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean $M$ and variance $V$.

The problem I'm having is that it seems like the distribution of the average should converge to something like a discrete variable with a [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) like $1$ at $M$ and $0$ everywhere else. This is because the strong LLN says the average must be $M$, as $n$ approaches infinity. Instead, the normal distribution given by the CLT seems to say that there's a chance of the average not being $M$, as $n$ approaches infinity, which seems to contradict the strong LLN.

Where's the flaw in my reasoning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you left out the scaling.  The average does converge to a constant: what converges to a normal distribution is 
$$\left(\text{average} - M\right)\sqrt{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Heres my 5 cents.

Central limit theorem states that:

If we have $X_1,X_2,\dots$ iid with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ then 
$$U_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\sigma ^2}} \sum _{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu) \to N(0,1)$$
in distribution.

Law of large numbers states that:

If $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d with mean $\mu$ then 
$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to \mu $$
a.s.

Returning to the CLT we can see it also shows that (since $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt n \sqrt n}$): 
$$\sqrt{n}\cdot (\frac{1}{n} \sum _{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)) \to N(0,\sigma ^2)$$

So you can see that CLT "works" a bit slower which is where the difference lies.

Convergence a.s. is much stronger than convergence in distribution, so you are right - had the scaling been the same it would imply convergence in distribution to a degenerate, that is almost surely constant random variable. In the case above $S_n \to X$ in distribution where $P(X=\mu)=1$

Maybe you can even now use CLT to say something about how fast the LLN convergence is?